# What is the meaning of the <FormState> syntax in the GlobalKey<FormState>?

Tags: flutter, dart

I saw a code like below.
I understood formKey is defined as GlobalKey type, and basically what `<FormState>` is? is this type as well?

I can declare field like `final formKey GlobalKey;` without any errors, but when I use `if (_formKey.currentState.validate())` later, flutter says validate() are not defined as methods and finally I'm confusing gramatically what `<FormState>` is, especially way of using <>?

Or Is this Generics? but I'm still confusing that i just learned that
we can use Generics  like  as type placeholder. But this code shown below seems not like that.
I'm sorry that I'm really new about class or objective programing’, and do appreciate your kindness!

```dart
class TEST extends ConsumerWidget {
final formKey GlobalKey<FormState>;
//omit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GlobalKey represents a key that is unique across your entire Flutter app. This is used to uniquely identify elements and provide access to objects that are associated to those elements. If the widget that has the global key associated, is stateful, the key also provide access to it's state.

If you check the GlobalKey class, you'll notice that it is declared as

```
abstract class GlobalKey<T extends State<StatefulWidget>> extends Key {}
```

In your case, the FormState should be a sub-class of State, which it is. The FormState represents the state associated to your form. The FormState can be used to save, reset, and validate every FormField in your Form.

TLDR: T is a generic, specifically a class that should extend `State<StatefulWidget>` . In your case it is used as the return type of   `T? get currentState {}` method and it represents the state of the associated form.

For your issue with the `validate()` method, you must actually write the `validate()` method and pass it to the `validator:` in the `TextFormField(validate: HERE)` widget. The method needs to return null if everything is ok, and the string with the validation error otherwise.

ex:

```
String? passwordValidator(String? value){
  if(value == null || value.isEmpty){
    return "Please fill this field";
  }else {
    return null;
   }
} //This is a very dummy validator, do not use it in production.
```

Comment: Really Thanks for your comment, and now I'm reading related official docs!
Finally can I say `<FormState>` itself is a sub-class of State and GlobalKey class should be set extended kinds of state class as generics to manage some key on Global scope level and those scope as well?

Comment: And it also means valiate() are methods belong to FormState class as well ?

Comment: You’re welcome! I don’t understand the “and those scope as well” part. You need to implement the validate() method yourself, and pass it to each TextFormField(). Does this answer to your comment?

Comment: Thank you so much, and I almost understood how to use validate() method so far. But I wonder which class define the method and  is it necesarry to set explicity like <FormState> as described above?

Comment: The method is defined in ```form.dart``` as ```typedef FormFieldValidator<T> = String? Function(T? value);```  I would say it's not necessary to set it explicitly because it will be inferred by dart, but it's a good practice to set it. For more info: https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system

Comment: Thanks again!  And maybe good morning in your country i guess.
And finally I could find that defined in FormState class as method in form.dart through my editor vscode. Also understood about setting it explicitly is good practice to make readable code or maintain my codes! I should say thank you again for your kindness!